# IR Camera artifact can anyone clarify

Tags: optics, camera, infrared

[image]I was wondering if anyone here could shed light on the recent “Jellyfish UFO” video recently reported on. This looks like bird poo on the housing to me, yet I am no expert and know very little about IR platforms. Has anyone with IR expertise seen the RAW video? I would be grateful if you would care to weigh with your knowledge on what they see and offer input on what could causes the effects displayed (i.e. tone changes etc). I’m Just seeking a little truth and logic in a crazy age. Thank you!
(Please delete if not permitted! Thanks!)

https://www.usatoday.com/story/news/nation/2024/01/11/jellyfish-ufo-uap-iraq-video/72194125007/

Comment: In IR, white is heat, black is cool. It looks like a sunny day (see dark shadows on fence post). So to me, this looks like leaves on a small tree or sapling. Leaves evaporate moisture, so that would suggest they would be cooler via evaporative cooling, and thus show as darker on IR.

Comment: So what you are saying is… please correct me if I misread- but are saying you watched the jellyfish video and came away with the conclusion of it being a flying tree leaf?

Comment: This is the video
https://youtu.be/AQgiIr2BjsI?si=Lt6bmhzxcu4Bb-mf

Comment: Nope, reacting to the image you posted